# how to set up high-availability kubernetes masters

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, high-availability

We need to deploy redundant haproxy load-balancers(VRRP) and 2~3 apiservers to build high-availability clusters on bare-metal

But, we have 4 bare-metal servers.(the number of nodes will increase)

So we are thinking of installing load-balancers in VMs assigned flat IPs on Master nodes, as you see the picture.

[image]

Is there any issues in this structure?
or please let me know better one..

Answer (score 1):

Seems like an overkill to build HA control plane and have one worker node, but I guess you plan to add more in future. Other then that it looks solid. Although I assume you also have some network equipment in the environment. This could open a possibility of ditching dedicated haproxy vrrp for apiserver in favor of having loadbalancer for it solved on ie. your router/gateway level.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response!.
Actually this is the first time I deploy HAproxy, so could you describe the possibility of ditching dedicated haproxy VRRP in more detail?

Comment: I mean that if you have a loadbalancer (or advances router / server)  handling your network, you can actually utilise it instead of doing everything from scratch (kind of like cloud loadbalancers are used in usual cloud based setups)

Comment: I see, Thanks a lot!!